# Specifying maximum depth with JAXRS?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs

I find myself in a weird spot using the Jackson JAX-RS provider. Say I have two simple classes;

```
class A {
    public class A() {}
    public B b;
}

class B {
    public class B() {}
    public A a;
}
```

And I do create some instances;

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.b = b;
b.a = a;
```

Basically a reverse link. If I try to serialize this, I get the expected stack overflow as it chases the circular reference forever. This is obviously a contrived example, but it reproduces the problem nicely. What I would like to do is somehow tell Jackson not to go past 1 level, so in my example, I'd expect something like;

```
{
  "b": {
      // don't serialize a again, but DO serialize every other property on b
  }
}
```

Is this doable? Am I stuck doing an ugly object mapping to get this to work?

Comment: I would assume you're fetching the object from database and directly giving that as input to the return statement?

Comment: It's actually a giant directed graph that's being queried. The problem is their mapping to objects is weak to say the least, they just lazy-load as the properties get accessed and I have zero control over how deep. So if i can't get Jackson to play nice, I probably have to create shadow objects and build mapper classes to populate them, which is inelegant to say the least.

Comment: I would do it by following two ways. But its not a standard way. Either create a Shadow object and tranfer your required fields from queried object to Shadow object OR use Projections directly in the Hibernate criteria to fetch only the required fields (It wont be good if there are lot and lot of fields to be fetched).. I too faced this kind of problem, but ended up using the former and later depending upon the number of fields and number of objects to be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly shadow objects wound up as the only viable option..